# How to verify more than 1 file exist with a given file extension in perl

Tags: perl, find, file-exists

My requirement is to know whether are at least 2 `.wav` files in a directory.

Currently I'm using `grep(/\.wav$/,readdir($dir))` to get the number of `.wav`  files exist and then check whether its `greater than 1`.

But I really don't want to count all the files if there were `1000s` of them.

Anyone have better solution for this...

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scalar context you can iterate over directory items using `while()`, and immediately break the loop when your condition is met,

```
my $count = 0;
while (defined(my $f = readdir $dir)) {
    if ($f =~ /\.wav$/ and ++$count >= 2) {
      print "there are at least two wav files\n";
      last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Сухой27. Better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` to expand the list of files in a directory with widcards, or better `bsd_glob` from package `File::Glob`:

```
use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';
my @wavfiles = bsd_glob("$your_directory/*.wav");
my $count_wavs = @wavfiles;
```

Note that the count of files is using an array in scalar context.

`bsd_glob` is better because it handles correctly spaces in directory names (amongst others), prefer this one on `glob`.

Comment: but still it counts all the files. Why count all the files to see whether there are at least 2 files.

Comment: Globbing may be slow if there are many files with the requested extension, else it is quite fast. Compared with the accepted solution, if your directory contains zz.wav and zzz.wav and many other files, the function may be quite long. Besides this point, I think it is simple enough to be used.